# postgresql - granting schema to users

Tags: postgresql

I have (2) postgresql databases. I basically used the same pg_dump export file to create the (2) db's on different machines. The DDL is the same, however, I am getting the `no relations` message on one of them. The search_path's are set correctly.  I believe I'm missing a grant for (2) of my users to see this schema. The settings are correct on Host2. I just don't which grant to use.

Message:

```
mra_prd_99999=> \dt
No relations found.
```

HOST1:

```
mra_prd_99999=> \z
                                                   Access privileges
      Schema       |           Name            | Type  |          Access privileges          | Column access privileges
-------------------+---------------------------+-------+-------------------------------------+--------------------------
 mra_dev_schm_99999 | abc_bounce_category       | table | mra_prd_99999=arwdDxt/mra_prd_99999 |
```

HOST2:

```
mra_prd_99999=> \z
                                                        Access privileges
      Schema       |           Name            | Type  |              Access privileges               | Column access privileges
-------------------+---------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+--------------------------
 mra_dev_schm_99999 | abc_bounce_category       | table | mra_prd_99999=arwdDxt/mra_prd_99999         +|
                   |                           |       | mra_prd_99999_user1=arwdDxt/mra_prd_99999+|
                   |                           |       | mra_prd_99999_user2=r/mra_prd_99999        |
```

My rolenames and settings are identical on both (1,2):

```
 mra_prd_99999          | Create DB                                      | {}
 mra_prd_99999_user1    |                                                | {}
 mra_prd_99999_user2    |                                                | {}
```

All the users have the search_path set to the same schema:

```
mra_prd_99999=> show search_path;
    search_path
-------------------
 mra_dev_schm_99999
(1 row)

mra_prd_99999=> \dn
          List of schemas
       Name        |     Owner
-------------------+---------------
 public            | mra
 mra_dev_schm_99999 | mra_prd_99999
(2 rows)
```

What grants do I need to run in order for HOST1's users to have the same access privileges than HOST2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the message

> No relations found.

because the user does not have the `USAGE` privilege on the schema (neither granted directly, nor through the `public` pseudorole).  You can check this by comparing `\dn+ mra_dev_schm_99999` on the two databases.

This is what the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) says about this:

> For schemas, allows access to objects contained in the specified
>   schema (assuming that the objects' own privilege requirements are also
>   met). Essentially this allows the grantee to "look up" objects within
>   the schema. Without this permission, it is still possible to see the
>   object names, e.g. by querying the system tables. Also, after revoking
>   this permission, existing backends might have statements that have
>   previously performed this lookup, so this is not a completely secure
>   way to prevent object access.

Furthermore, it appears that the two `mra_prd_99999_user`s don't have the table level privileges on `abc_bounce_category` - you have to do

```
GRANT ALL ON TABLE mra_dev_schm_99999.abc_bounce_category 
      TO mra_prd_99999_user1;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE mra_dev_schm_99999.abc_bounce_category 
      TO mra_prd_99999_user2;
```

If you have more tables with the same problem, do

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA mra_dev_schm_99999 
      TO mra_prd_99999_user1;

-- then for future tables:
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE mra_prd_99999 
    IN SCHEMA mra_dev_schm_99999 GRANT ALL ON TABLES 
    TO mra_prd_99999_user1;

-- and similarly to the other user
```

Comment: Understood so far at the table level and for each table. Would this work then if I wanted to do all the tables then? `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE mra_prd_99999 IN SCHEMA mra_dev_schm_99999 GRANT ALL ON TABLES  TO mra_prd_99999_user1;`

Comment: Partly yes, see my edit.